# How can I add 'knowledge' to my model?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I need to predict some continuous data. How can I add knowledge about a range to the model? For example: dataset about morphology to predict value of red bloodcells. From knowledge from doctors or books we know that for example value cannot be negative and that value are in some allowable range, how to give that knowledge to a model?

Comment: change the output layer activation function to match the distribution you are targetting

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for Bayesian statistics. I'd suggest learning a PPL like Stan or [Turing.jl](https://turing.ml/), and using that to model your problem.